# Customizing comfortable_mexican_sofa database table names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, comfortable-mexican-sofa

In a Rails 4 project using comfortable_mexican_sofa gem for content management, how do you change the default database table names?

I'd like to remove the 'comfy_' prefix so they are just 'cms_blocks', 'cms_pages', etc...

Answer (score 3):

```
class ComfyWhateverElseMore < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "whatever_you_wish"
end
```

For reference consider the  [api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name)

Comment: That answer is Sofa King great!

Comment: Right, I'm aware of how to customize ActiveRecord model table names. I attempted to do this very thing for the 'comfortable_mexican_sofa' gem's various models without luck. Hoping for feedback in the context of this package specifically.

Comment: After further digging I opened an issue given I found hardcoded table names in scopes. May not be possible given conventional approaches https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/issues/675